# Receiving the key value pair as input parameter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json-deserialization

I am trying to receive the below key value pair as the input parameter to my Web API

```
json=%7B%0A%22MouseSampleBarcode%22%20%3A%20%22MOS81%22%0A%7D%0A
```

where the right of the string is the URL encoded JSON which looks like

```
{
"MouseSampleBarcode" : "MOS81"
}
```

How can I parse this and store them in to the Model class

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromBody] CoreBarCodeDTO.RootObject coreBarCode)
 {
  string Bar_Code = coreBarCode.MouseSampleBarcode.ToString();
```

where the CoreBarCodeDTO looks like below

```
public class CoreBarCodeDTO
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string MouseSampleBarcode { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Get doesn't have body.

Comment: The easiest would be to remove `json=...` and replace it by proper parameters. Is this possible for you?

Comment: @Lokki Got [HttpPost] in the Get. But how does the URL encoded JSON gets decoded also how to deal with json=

Comment: Your controller is receiving a form url encoded content that will not deserialize to a `CorBarCodeDTO` because it has no property named `json`. You might consider accepting a `FormDataCollection` parameter in your controller then decode and deserialize the value of the `json` key.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I dont have the control over that. how can the URL encoded JSON get decoded also how to deal with json=

Comment: @Crowcoder how do I include the property json in to `CoreBarCodeDTO`

Comment: Could you provide the request you need to proceed in your controller?

Comment: @Lokki I am not following you. I am trying to get the `MOS81` from the input parameter and store them in a string. But the input parameter is URL encoded JSON with `json=`

Comment: Try changing the parameter to `string json` and then convert the string to JSON with a library like Newtonsoft.Json -> `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)`

Comment: @Crowcoder can you please tell me how can I use the FormDataCollection here

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy does the Nwtonsoft.Json alos take care of the URL decoding?

Comment: Is `json=%7B%0A%22MouseSampleBarcode%22%20%3A%20%22MOS81%22%0A%7D%0A` a part of the body or url?

Comment: @Lokki It is the Body

Comment: Why is it url encoded? Can you change the request?

Comment: @xyz At the point where you have the `json` parameter available the string would be URL decoded already. Newtsoft.JSON just converts the string to a object of type `RootObject`. See @Crowcoder answer, tha'ts what i ment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way. Change your class to this definition. In your controller `coreBarCode.json` will have the the json which you can then work with as needed:

```
public class CoreBarCodeDTO
{
    private string _json;
    public string json { get { return _json; }
        set {
            string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value);
            _json = decoded;
        }
    }
}
```

> Update

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromBody] CoreBarCodeDTOcoreBarCode coreBarCode)
 {
    string Bar_Code = coreBarCode.json;
    //work with the JSON here, with Newtonsoft for example
    var obj = JObject.Parse(Bar_Code);
    // obj["MouseSampleBarcode"] now = "MOS81"

 }
```

Comment: What is coreBarCode here? May be I am little confused

Comment: It is the argument to your controller.

Comment: Also how do I access the MOS81 as string here?

Comment: There is no single way, but I have updated an example of parsing the JSON with Newtonsoft which you may need to add a reference to.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lokki mentioned in his comment. The GET verb does not have a body, you need to change that to POST or PUT (depending if you are creating/searching or updating), so your code would look like this:

```
[HttpPost("/")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromBody] CoreBarCodeDTO.RootObject coreBarCode)
{ 
   string Bar_Code = coreBarCode.MouseSampleBarcode.ToString();
```

Comment: I missed while pasting. I have [HttpPost] even then it is not working

Answer (score 0):

So, as I said: Get doesn't have body. 
Follow @KinSlayerUY answer.

```
[HttpPost("/")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] CoreBarCodeDTO.RootObject coreBarCode)
{ 
   string Bar_Code = coreBarCode.MouseSampleBarcode.ToString();
   ...
}
```

If you need use GET remove `[FromBody]` attribute and send data as single parameters

```
[HttpGet("/")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string mouseSampleBarcode)
{ 
   var rootObject = new CoreBarCodeDTO.RootObject
   {
        MouseSampleBarcode = mouseSampleBarcode
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: OP is going against convention with naming but this is not the problem.